# Spawn a new process in docker container which image is built from scratch

Tags: go, docker

I'm trying to build a minimal docker image (`FROM scratch`) that contains 2 executable binaries. Both are binaries built with Go. The entrypoint is set to the first one. It takes some data on the image, transforms it using environment variables, starts a new process executing the second binary and pipes the data as an input for the spawned process.

```
FROM scratch
COPY bin /opt/my-app
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/my-app/first", "--run", "/opt/my-app/second"]
```

When I build this image on my Mac, everything works fine. But when it's created it on our build server running linux, the first process cannot start the second one. It fails with an error "fork/exec /opt/my-app/second: no such file or directory". However, "second" binary does exist. In both cases docker engine 1.13.1 is used.

It also works if parent image is changed from `scratch` to `debian:jessie`.

Are there any limitations of the scratch image that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Are the binaries statically linked?  With a scratch image there will not be a libc (or any shared libs).  If it works fine on debian, then I suspect the binary is not statically linked, which is the normal default.  Try CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -a -installsuffix cgo as seen here http://www.blang.io/posts/2015-04_golang-alpine-build-golang-binaries-for-alpine-linux/

Comment: Thanks for the hint, setting CGO_ENABLED=0 does help. If you post it as an answer, I'll be happy to accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a scratch image there will not be a libc (or any shared libs). If it works fine on debian, then I suspect the binary is not statically linked, which is the normal default. Try CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -a -installsuffix cgo as seen here http://www.blang.io/posts/2015-04_golang-alpine-build-golang-binaries-for-alpine-linux/